# Can a large (but not large enough to crash) javascript heap (not just excessive scripting or dom elements) slow down a website?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I am using angular material dialog, with mat stepper three tables (one per step), one or two of them may contain thousands of records. I have already implemented (material) virtual scrolling. Switching between steps will be choppy in IE, as does scrolling down, and there's a delay when I click on step one's form (the *other* steps are tables), there's a delay on the blur of the form field. I am not at the point where the heap is "too large" to where the site crashes, and it works fine in chrome...but is the fact that the heap is simply large (520 mb) going to simply make things slower?

Comment: https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/f034-hertz.pdf - interesting reading wrt. paging and GC.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can cause a slowdown if the user's machine has to resort to using virtual memory/paging file to compensate for the large heap. Beyond that, it might cause trivial slowdowns in garbage collection, but that's hardly even worth mentioning.